# I have list with multiple strings and I want to search some patterns in substring of the string and print the next, previous line of pattern in python

Tags: python, list, string-matching

From the list first I have to check what all are the values contains **start** and **end** keyword. If the value contains start/end then it should print inbetween lines of these values.

**Input:**

```
list1 = ['started','1','asd', 'ending of the word/n','aaaa','startin','answer','fruit','123','ending']
```

**Expected output:**

```
['1',asd]
['answer','fruit','123']
```

```
    for x in list1:
        if start in x:
           substring1 = x
        if end in x:
           substring2 = x
```

After this I need to print the values between substring1 and substring2 variable. I don't know how to proceed further. I am also new to python. Can someone help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['started', '1', 'asd', 'ending of the word/n', 'aaaa', 'startin', 'answer', 'fruit', '123', 'ending']
index_start = 0
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if 'start' in list1[i]:
        index_start = i
    if 'end' in list1[i]:
        print(list1[index_start+1:i])
```

Working with `i in range()` in your `for` loop is more appropriate so that you can get the indexes of where the patterns start/end. Then simply store the `start_index` when you find 'start' and print everything in between when you find the 'end' substring.

Of course you'd want to add some conditions to make sure there is a start before an end.

Output:

```
['1', 'asd']
['answer', 'fruit', '123']
```

Comment: list1 = ['start','started','1','asd', 'ending of the word/n','start','end','end,'aaaa','startin','answer','fruit','123','ending']                              
Expected Output:                        
['1',asd] [ ] ['answer','fruit','123']                                                                                                                                           In this case how to skip the 7th index value because there is no start keyword before the 7th index. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qFQw7Rvf as I stated you must add a condition for other cases